# RestAPI в yii фрэймворк

Tags: php, yii2

Решил изучить php фрэймворк - Yii. Столкнулся с проблемой минимальной настройки restAPI. Вот, что у меня есть:

Файл config/web.php

```
...
'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'base']
        ]
...
```

Файл controllers/BaseController.php

```
...

    namespace app\controllers;

    use yii\rest\ActiveController;

    class BaseController extends ActiveController
    {
        public $modelClass = 'app\models\Base';
    }

...
```

Файл models/Base.php

```
namespace app\models;

class Base extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $id;
    public $id_user;
    public $name;
    public $hidden;

}
```

Подключение к базе есть.

По запросу `GET localhost/bases` получаю в ответ список объектов из базы, но (!) почему-то все их поля равны `null`. Когда пытаюсь создать новый объект с помощью `POST localhost/bases`, то без разницы, что я передаю в параметрах, создаётся новая строка в базе, но все поля в ней равны null

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

решил вопрос таким образом

добавил в контроллер метод

```
public function actionList() {
  return Base::find()->asArray()->all();
}
```

а в роуте

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'base',
    'extraPatterns' => [
         'GET list' => 'list',
    ],
]
```

теперь по запросу localhost/base/list получаю нормальный список

не совсем restAPI в итоге, но тоже решение